# Mysql error - Cannot connect: invalid settings.

Tags: mysql, database, xampp, wamp

I was working on some tables in mysql, and out of no where, i got an error (Cannot start session without errors, please check errors given in your PHP and/or webserver log file and configure your PHP installation properly.) Then i uninstalled xampp and tried to reinstall it. Then i got the error (phpMyAdmin tried to connect to the MySQL server, and the server rejected the connection. You should check the host, username and password in your configuration and make sure that they correspond to the information given by the administrator of the MySQL server.)

How can i get access again?

Comment: _"please check errors given in your PHP and/or webserver log file "_ Did you do what it says? What were the errors?

Comment: where is the log file located?